# Error with connection: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a Web Application using Java Servlets.  I am trying to implement login, logout, and registration functionality but I'm a little confused on how to get everything working.  Here is the code for the Login page:

```
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package hw5package;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@cci-ora02.uncc.edu:1521:class";
        String username = "teverha4";
        String password = "qwe123";

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>ITIS 4166 Project</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<div align='center'>");
        out.println("<h1>ITIS 4166 Project - Login Page</h1>");
        out.println("<h2>by: Tyler Everhart</h2>");

        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");

        out.println("<table width='20%' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>");
        out.println("<form id='loginForm' name='loginForm' method='POST'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='006F13' align='left' colspan='2'><b>Login</b></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Username:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='username' id='username' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passUsername = request.getParameter("username");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Password:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='password' name='pwd' id='pwd' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passPwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='006F13' align='center' colspan='2'>");
        out.println("<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='loginValidation()' /> ");
        out.println("<input type='reset' value='Reset' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("<a href='Registration'>New User, Click Here to Register</a>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT UserName, PassWord FROM UserLogin";

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            if ((passUsername.equals(resultSet.getString("UserName")) && passPwd.equals(resultSet.getString("PassWord")))) {
                String sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                session.setAttribute("username", passUsername);
                session.setAttribute("sessionID", sessionID);
                response.sendRedirect("Categories");
            }
            else if (passUsername.equals("") || passPwd.equals("")) {
                out.println("Enter a username and password.");
            }
            else {
                out.println("Either your username or password is incorrect or could not be found.");
                out.println("Please try again, or click the link below to register.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println("Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
        out.println("<tr>Error loading driver: " + cnfe + "</tr>");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println("Error with connection: " + sqle);
        out.println("<tr>Error with connection: " + sqle + "</tr>");
    }
    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Here is the code for the Registration page:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hw5package;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
public class Registration extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@cci-ora02.uncc.edu:1521:class";
        String username = "teverha4";
        String password = "qwe123";

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>ITIS 4166 Project</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<div align='center'>");
        out.println("<h1>ITIS 4166 Project - Registration Page</h1>");
        out.println("<h2>by: Tyler Everhart</h2>");

        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");

        out.println("<table width='25%' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th bgcolor='006F13' align='left' colspan='2'>Register Account Information</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Requested Username:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<form id='enterForm' name='enterForm'>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='requested_username' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passUsername = request.getParameter("requested_username");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Password:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='password' name='pwd' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passPwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Confirm Password:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='password' name='pwd1' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passPwd1 = request.getParameter("pwd1");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='006F13' align='center' colspan='2'>");
        out.println("<input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' /> ");
        out.println("<input type='reset' value='Reset' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (passPwd.equals("") || passPwd1.equals("")) {
            Integer registerError = Integer.valueOf(1);
            session.setAttribute("registerError", registerError);
            out.println("Please enter a valid password.");
        }
        else if (!passPwd.equals(passPwd1)) {
            Integer registerError = Integer.valueOf(2);
            session.setAttribute("registerError", registerError);
            out.println("Your password and confirm password does not match.");
        }
        else {
            String query2 = "INSERT INTO UserLogin (UserName, PassWord, StockAmt, TechnologyStock, UtilityStock) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
            stmt.setString(1, passUsername);
            stmt.setString(2, passPwd);
            stmt.setInt(3, 0);
            stmt.setInt(4, 0);
            stmt.setInt(5, 0);
            stmt.executeQuery();
            session.setAttribute("sessionUsername", passUsername);
            String sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            Random StockID1 = new Random();
            StockID1.nextInt(10);
            String insertDataSqlMicrosoft = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID1 + "','" + passUsername + ",'Technology','Microsoft (MSFT)',0,32.75,0";
            PreparedStatement stmtMicrosoft = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlMicrosoft);
            stmtMicrosoft.executeQuery();

            Random StockID2 = new Random();
            StockID2.nextInt(4);
            String insertDataSqlIntel = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID2 + "','" + passUsername + "','Technology','Intel (INTC)',0,26.75,0)";
            PreparedStatement stmtIntel = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlIntel);
            stmtIntel.executeQuery();

            Random StockID3 = new Random();
            StockID3.nextInt(9);
            String insertDataSqlDuke = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID3 + "','" + passUsername + "','Utility','Duke Energy (DUK)',0,89.00,0";
            PreparedStatement stmtDuke = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlDuke);
            stmtDuke.executeQuery();

            Random StockID4 = new Random();
            StockID4.nextInt(7);
            String insertDataSqlCable = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID4 + "','" + passUsername + "','Utility','Time Warner Cable (TWC)',0,30.00,0)";
            PreparedStatement stmtCable = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlCable);
            stmtCable.executeQuery();

            session.setAttribute("sessionID", sessionID);
            response.sendRedirect("Categories");
        }
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println("Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
        out.println("<tr>Error loading driver: " + cnfe + "</tr>");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println("Error with connection: " + sqle);
        out.println("<tr>Error with connection: " + sqle + "</tr>");
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

I figured out the problem that I was having before with reading from the database only to now have a new problem.  When I type in a username and password that I have verified are present in the database I am not redirected to the page that I want to go to.  Also when I try to register a new user I am not redirected to the page and am given an error that says:

Error with connection: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

The username and password for the person registering are sent to the database but the program doesn't redirect you to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your driver class and URL syntax.

Syntax for URL connection is

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

Here is a working sample I got from [OracleFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC).

```
import java.sql.*;
class Conn {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
   Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl", "scott", "tiger");
                        // @//machineName:port/SID,   userid,  password
   try {
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     try {
       ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select BANNER from SYS.V_$VERSION");
       try {
         while (rset.next())
           System.out.println (rset.getString(1));   // Print col 1
       } 
       finally {
          try { rset.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
       }
     } 
     finally {
       try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
     }
   } 
   finally {
     try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
   }
  }
}
```

There are few more things I would like to suggest.

- If you are allowed to use JSP, please go for [MVC](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/jw-12-ssj-jspmvc.html) design.
- As you might have noticed, you have duplicate code in both your
  classes. So create a separate class for database connection.

To find the correct hostname/port/service, check tnsnames.ora file. 
Check [OracleFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)

Here are few more links to get you started:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/getsta.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html

Comment: I'm still having problems with my code.  I don't know if I don't have the right host name, port number, or service.  Or is it possible that I need to download a program for the database functionality or what.

Comment: You need a JDBC connector. If this is your first time with database connectivity, I suggest you try a simple servlet that displays contents of a db table.